# Camera feed interferring with Barcode data

Tags: c#, webcam, barcode-scanner, keylogger

I am working on an application that collects text from a barcode scanner and inserts into a database, then captures an image almost immediately.

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // check timing (keystrokes within 100 ms)
    TimeSpan elapsed = (DateTime.Now - _lastKeystroke);
    if (elapsed.TotalMilliseconds > 100)
        _barcode.Clear();

    // record keystroke & timestamp
    _barcode.Add(e.KeyChar);
    _lastKeystroke = DateTime.Now;

    // process barcode
    if (e.KeyChar == 13 && _barcode.Count > 0)
    {
        string barcode_value = new String(_barcode.ToArray());
        using (MySqlConnection conn = getConnection()) {
            MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO log (card_number) VALUE (?barcode_value)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?barcode_value", barcode_value);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            lastId = cmd.LastInsertedId;
            _barcode.Clear();

            Image img = imgVideo.Image;
            Helper.AutoSave(img, dirPath + lastId.ToString() + ".jpg");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I am not using an API, instead I'm checking key presses (using time between first and last character as well as last character entered) to determine if I'm getting data from the barcode scanner. For the camera part I am using  [WebCam Library](http://easywebcam.codeplex.com/), and it is initialized and started (on form load) thus:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webcam = new WebCam();
    webcam.InitializeWebCam(ref imgVideo);
    webcam.Start();
}
```

The problem with the application is, calling `webcam.Start()` for some reason causes the data scanned (from barcode) to be truncated. On some occasions, the last three characters are captured on some others no character is captured at all; the image is captured, alright. If I remove everything pertaining to the camera the barcode scanning part works as expected.

**UPDATE:** I was adviced that [IRQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_request_%28PC_architecture%29) is the reason behind this conflict, can anyone shed more light on this and how it can be solved.

Comment: Would using StopWatch be better than DateTime? I'd be concerned about the precision needed for this code to work.

Comment: @DougDawson No, everything works fine as is; just need to resolve why the camera is causing a truncation of barcode data (so, both can work together).